# Python/HTML: how to write csv file to a sheet.html?

Tags: python, html, csv, post, writer

I need to write the data received from the form to a csv file that needs to be displayed on the sheet.html page. The data is put into the csv file and once the form it is submitted, the server redirects to the sheet.html but the csv is not shown on this page.

```
import cs50
import csv

from flask import Flask, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Reload templates when they are changed
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """Disable caching"""
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Expires"] = 0
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    return response

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def get_index():
    return redirect("/form")

@app.route("/form", methods=["GET"])
def get_form():
    return render_template("form.html")

@app.route("/form", methods=["POST"])
def post_form():
    with open("survey.csv", "a") as file:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = ["First", "Last", "Clubs"])
        writer.writerow({"First": request.form.get("fname"), "Last": request.form.get("lname"), "Clubs": request.form.get("clubs")})
        file.close()
    return redirect ("/sheet")

@app.route("/sheet", methods=["GET"])
def get_sheet():
    with open("survey.csv", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)
        students = list(reader)
    return render_template("sheet.html", students=students)

{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block main %}

<table class = "table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Club</th>

        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        {% for student in students %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ student["First"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ student["Last"] }}</td>
          <td>{{ student["Clubs"] }}</td>

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx